# What Design Patterns are Found in Real-World Spring Roo Applications?

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to understand the architecture of (real-world, not pedagogical examples) Spring Roo applications. Not that I suppose there's only *one* architecture but I do suppose that a handful of patterns would likely describe the majority of Spring Roo applications. Hence my question, what are these patterns?

My difficulty is that I haven't been able to find examples of real-world applications on the web or in books. *Not that I haven't looked diligently*. I have. In fact I think that I deserve medals both for stubborn persistence and creative querying. (If you think I've missed something then please offer the evidence. But don't insult your own intelligence by suggesting I haven't spent adequate time on the search. For starters, I've got every one of the three published books on the subject. And I've spent many late-night hours Googling for examples.)

Here's what I've  found. The vast majority of available examples are very small and obviously intended to make a pedagogical point rather than serve as a real-world implementation. Of the handful of larger examples, *none that I've found actually compiles* (So to speak, as Roo is not a compiler as such. What I mean is that the failure occurs before runtime.). Most often this is because the Roo language has changed, outdating the example as to its syntax. But such changes *may* also entail changes in the architecture of Roo applications. As a careful researcher I can't gratuitously presume that's not the case. So any example that doesn't compile is no example at all, for my purposes. (As to compiling without error, the ongoing example in the book *Spring Roo in Action* might possibly be an exception. I haven't managed to work through the entire book because it includes lengthy discourses on Spring. These are useful, even important. But they're not directly pertinent to the syntax and semantics of Roo itself, which is my current concern. In any case, although the example is more elaborate than most I've seen, it doesn't appear to me to include the full range of real-world functionality. If I'm wrong then my count of relevant examples is off by only one.)

So, given the lack of examples, I have no idea what a real-world application might look like. I'm not even sure what the menu of functionality looks like because I'm not yet sure what can, and can't, be accomplished in Roo. The absence of relevant examples is an important absence. The first time I saw a complete, working system, back in the late 60s or early 70s, it looked not at all like the examples in my programming textbook. I suspect the same is true of Roo. So, please help me out. What functionality is being implemented in Roo? Or, from a more detailed perspective, what do Roo's design patterns look like? (If there are technological limits, I'd be curious to learn more, though that issue might be off topic. I mean, if Roo fumbles--performance-wise, let alone functionally--when more than 10-15 database tables are involved, that's important to know up front!)

Frankly, I begin to worry that no one is actually using Spring Roo for real-world development. Even if you can't share your code, I'd be interested in knowing that some folks here are using Roo for development.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo is a helper to start and maintain a Spring-based project. Roo helps you to create the base on grow up a complex spring application. Whenever you want, you can [remove all Roo dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html) to get a standard Spring + AspectJ application.

We are developing application using Spring Roo. Now, I'm working in a project with more than a hundred entities (and soon I have to create around twenty new entities in next version) which currently is in production stage. So, in my experience, I think you can use Spring Roo to create a real-world application.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Roo can be, and is being, used for actual development--and reasonably large-scale development, at that. Can you disclose anything about architecture? I mean, you mention two mutually exclusive structures: one in which the application is indefinitely maintained as a Roo application and another in which the Roo-related parts of the system are thrown away. (I understand the technology, thanks--in other words, what *can* be done; my questions concern what's *actually being* done).

Comment: By the way, although I am an advocate of open source, I do understand/agree there can be valid business reasons *not* to disclose the source code or architecture of a system and that developers are often not, in any case, the makers of those decisions. So please don't take offense at my questions. I *have to ask* but I have no quarrel with one who refuses to answer.